# When is the short u sound as in fun spelled with the letter A?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Can you give me examples of when it's spelled with the letter A?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your reason for asking this question? Do you consider the stressed vowel in *f**u**n* and *str**u**t* to be the same as the unstressed one that you say at the start of ***a**bout* and at the end of *sof**a***?

Comment: This is a question on NPR's Sunday Puzzler with WIll Shortz, Sun Feb 4

Comment: This question should be on https://puzzles.stackexchange.com, or rather, in the interests of the show it came from, locked until after the puzzle deadline which is next Thursday

Answer (score 2):

tundra, cannabis (the second 'a'), menacing, America, ago

In phonetics, the sound you're referring to is portrayed like this 'ə'. It is also called schwa. It's usually the sound of unstressed vowels. It happens with every vowel, not just 'a'.

Comment: I demonstrate that "any" spelling can lead to schwa [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/428929/2085).