# Spelling of temperature and preparation

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Today, I have come up with the two confusingly-spelled words: **temperature** and **preparation**.

The 'para' in pre**para**tion, and the 'pera' in tem**pera**tion, look quite similar in pronunciation when we read those two words out loud. Hence, new language learners might get confused whether to spell tem**pera**ture as tem**para**ture or tem**pra**ture. Also, they might get confused in spelling pre**para**tion as pre**pra**tion or pre**pera**tion.

> **In a nut shell:**
>
> - Why can't we spell tem**pera**ture as tem**para**ture or tem**pra**ture, if they all give the same pronunciation?
> - Why can't we spell pre**para**tion as pre**pra**tion or pre**pera**tion?

Is there any spelling rule in writing such words properly? Are there other words (containing pra, pera and para) apart from temperature and preparation?

Comment: I wouldn't pronounce them the same if they were spelled that way.

Comment: I agree with @Jim that your first question is moot because those would not all give the same pronunciation.  (On the other hand, as many people are fond of pointing out here, spelling and pronunciation are not necessarily related.)

Comment: Related: [Can the schwa sound predict spelling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428925) See my answer there. Both "er" and "ar" are possible spellings of /ər/.

Comment: 1) 'preparation' obviously comes from 'prepare', so there is some expectation to spell them the same whatever the actual pronunciation. 2) Also, English has lots of exceptions to spelling rules, maybe more. So you just have to deal with it. 3) We can't spell them as you suggest because that's not how spelling works, or at least not that quickly. You cant just say "Let's do it this (maybe) better way" had then everybody follows. If people tend to misspell consistently, then maybe it will catch on (like 'alright' for 'all right'). But people don't tend to misspell these two words.

Comment: Why are you thinking that spelling is about pronunciation? It's not: it's about etymology. This has more downstream affects than you realize. For example, even though people could say "temprature" they cannot say "prepration", which shows that these are not the same the way you think they are.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think the difference in acceptability between "temp'rature" and "prep'ration" is related to the spelling. I think it's because in "preparation", the syllable containing the schwa comes immediately  before a stressed syllable. The word "operation" is spelled with "er", but I think "op'ration" is no more common than "prep'ration". See the quote in my answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/308642/77227 For speakers who pronounce "preparatory" with stress on the first syllable, I think the elided form "prep'ratory" is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, of course, use any spelling you wish. If you use unconventional spellings such as "preperation" in a formal setting, such as an academic paper, the reader may regard your work as inferior, which would interfere with your academic purpose.

There are many rules for English spelling, but most of them are wrong at least some of the time. English borrowed heavily from other languages during its development. Because of this, many things about English are irregular.

For more information, good starting points may be these *Wikipedia* articles:

- “[Prestige (sociolinguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics))”
- “[English orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography)”
- “[English-language spelling reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform)”